# Kotlin multiplatform with cocoapods

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

I have module "firebase" in KMM project, in this module i added "FirebaseCore" via cocoapods.

```
 cocoapods {
        version = "2.0.0"
        // Configure the fields as necessary
        summary = "Some description for the Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to the Kotlin/Native module home page"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "16.4" // use your desired iOS version

        pod("FirebaseCore")
        pod("FirebaseAuth")
    }
```

I want to use module "firebase" in module "app".

```
val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project(":firebase"))
            }
        }
```

When i try build ios framework of module "app" i got error

```
ld: framework not found FirebaseCore
```

I tryed use "api" expect implementation